# Drupal Content View Show entities referenced via user reference field

Tags: entity-framework, drupal, entity, view

Using Drupal 7, Views and Entity API I am trying to create a View which shows the logged in User all downloads which are available to him.

I use the following Content Types:

- **Software**
- **Software Pack**

The **User** has an entity reference field that accepts 1 value to reference a **Software Pack**.
*user_software_pack*

The **Software Packs** include an entity reference field that accepts unlimited values to reference **Software** included in the Pack.
*field_included_software*

For the View I am creating an unformated list of Content Teasers of Type **Software**

Doing this shows me all Software that is published, I am now attempting to filter the list to only the Software available to the User using the following relationships.

- A bridge to the User entity that is referencing Content via *field_software_pack*
- A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via *field_software_pack*
- A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via *field_included_software*

To me this would translate getting the user, then using that to reference the Software Pack to then reference the Software in that Pack.
The view shows me all Software entities. Am I missing something?

Setting the Show: Content settings to use the relationship gives me an empty view, setting a relationship as required provides an empty view as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a lengthy break and coming back to the problem I managed to solve it.

For anyone who might get stuck on a similar problem:
I was using one relationship too much.

My view shows al content of type **Software**.
**Software** is referenced in multiple **Software Packs** *(field_included_software)* and the **User profile** has a reference field *(field_software_pack)* to 1 **Software Pack**.

To filter the view of content type **Software** it requires first setting up a relationship to the **Software Packs** that are referencing **Software**.

- A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Content via field_included_software

Then it needs another relationship to the **User Profile** referencing which **Software Pack** the user has.

- A bridge to the User entity that is referencing Content via field_software_pack

To get the User ID of the logged in user to limit the results to only the **Software** in the **Software Pack** of the user a contextual filter is needed.

- User: Uid

The contextual filter is set to provide a default value from PHP Code:

```
$uid = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;
return $uid;
```

Relationship for the contextual filter is set to the User reference.

All relationships have to be set as REQUIRED.

Once I configured my view like this everything worked as planned.