# Drupal 7 content view filter on logged in user account field

Tags: drupal-7, view, relationship

I have a Drupal 7 content view. Displays a grid of content of type vb1.
Each vb1 node has a multi-valued entity ref field, place. 
The currently logged in user has in their account profile a field, myplace, where one and only one of the places has been selected.

I need the view to only show vb1 nodes for which myplace (in the user profile) is among one of the entries in the vb1 place.

None of the relationships I've tried to the user has worked. 
Can anyone suggest a solution?

By the way, I've looked at:
[Drupal Content View Show entities referenced via user reference field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843283/drupal-content-view-show-entities-referenced-via-user-reference-field)
Nothing there worked for me.
Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Main issue is that when adding a view-relationship to a user account field (in the example, it is field_myplace), nothing is returned from the user account. So I cannot filter without that.

Comment: Added computed field to vb1 content type.

global $user;
$myaccount = user_load($user->uid);
$myplace = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items('user', $myaccount, 'field_place')));
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $myplace;